# How to open square brackets of the sum?

Tags: sums-of-squares

For example
Σ(y[i]-mean(y[i]))^2 = ? 
Please describe the way how it opens.

Comment: What do you mean by open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Denote $\bar y=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^ny_i}{n}.$ Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-\bar{y})^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i^2-2\bar{y}y_i+\bar y^2)=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-2\bar{y}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\bar y^2.$$

What is the relation between $\sum_{i=1}^ny_i$ and $\bar y?$ How can you simplify the whole expression?

Comment: Thank you. So it equals Σy[i]^2-mean(y)*Σy[i],right?

Comment: Yes. You can also write it as $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2-n\bar{y}^2.$